# GoogleMaps InfoWindow appear at a corner

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

here is my code in html to generate marker and infowindow(with ruby on rails)

```
 var marker=[]
   function initMap() {

     var latLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(1.352083, 103.819836);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 12,
         center: latLng1,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

     for(i=0;i<gon.astatic.length;i++){


      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(gon.astatic[i][1], gon.astatic[i][2]);
       if(i<2){
       marker[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({position: latLng, map: map,icon:"/assets/green_MarkerV.png" ,labelClass: "labels",labelContent: gon.astatic[i][3]});}
       else
       {
      marker[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({position: latLng, map: map,icon:"/assets/green_MarkerN.png" ,labelClass: "labels",labelContent: gon.astatic[i][3]});
       }


     var iw =new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'HI' });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i],"mouseover",function(e){iw.open(map,marker[i]);})

     }
```

this gon is just some 'stupid' method I use to pass data from ruby on rails controller to javascript.

for all marker,the infowindow all appear at corner.
But for my another map(which have only one marker with infowindow)it works fine.

[image: This infowindow shift to corner]
What might be my problem?why this infowindow appear in wrong position?Instead of just above the marker?

**EDIT:**

After half day's trouble shoot,I feel the problem is at
  `google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i],"mouseover",function(e){iw.open(map,marker[i]);})`

when the listener calls back,the value inside marker is i ,which is not a actual number,so the marker display at a corner.I feel the problem is can't pass variable into addListener,can only put in actual number.How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of the function declared inside the for loop shares the same closure containing the value `i`, and so all of your addListener calls are essentially calling `iw.open(map, undefined)` since `i` will be off the end of the array at the end of the iteration.

See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for sample solutions to this problem, and [How do JavaScript closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111111#111111) for more information about closures in JavaScript in general.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `MarkerWithLabel` library. Infowindow take position from marker. Try use this link http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/examples.html . It has all the things that you want to implement. It it's not work then you can also set position for infowindow with `setPosition()` function just pass latlng that you used to create marker and you are done.

Comment: Thank you~your link is help full,but my info window syntax same as this link,and the infowinds works fine for single marker.so I think is some internal problem?

Answer (score 1):

i dont recommend using new gem just to pass data from ruby to js...you can do this simply by many ways...your code seems good but i cannot say how `gon` is handling your js script.Please take a look at this similar question where i have implemented the same **dynamic** `map` with **dynamic** `markers` and `infowindows`.This code is working great

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832979/show-multiple-markers-on-google-maps-dynamically-using-resultset-returned-rails/24849179#24849179)